False Google Drive v3 disk usage quota error
some users of my android/java app have reported that they can't upload a file to Google Drive.
The app uploads files to one specific Google Drive account.
I checked the logs and I saw this:
"domain": "usageLimits",
"message": "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded.",
"reason": "storageQuotaExceeded".

So naturally, I checked the storage space and I got about 7GB left. Also checked storageQuota by using https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/about/get and it confirmed what I saw in the UI:
{
  "storageQuota": {
    "limit": "16106127360",
    "usage": "7298236418",
    "usageInDrive": "7298236418",
    "usageInDriveTrash": "0"
  }
}

As you can see, I got plenty of space left.
I also checked the user's Google Drive's space and they also have a lot of space there.
Has anyone encountered similar problem?

Please edit your question and include [example] also are you using a service account by chance?

Possible duplicate of Node JS Google Drive api error: The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded
